# My car wont start then a flame 

Tags: electrical, starting, mechanics-trade

Quick background info I have a 2010 lincoln mks , & it is push to start. I tried starting my car multiple times it wouldnt start, just clicking so i looked under the hood to look at my battery and i saw a small orange flame on the right hand side towards the back, AAA wasn’t able to help other than testing the battery (which the battery was still good)

would anyone have any suggestion on what might be the problem?

Please help, thanks

Comment: Can you add a photo and an arrow where the flame was?

Comment: Was the flame only there while trying to start the engine?

Comment: I'm assuming me trying to start the engine is what caused it, when I stopped trying to start it I then checked under the hood and saw the flame. the flame was orange & not too big it when out on its own about 5mins later. I'm not with my car now but when I return home I will attach a picture